# What's the best way to get posts from one multisite blog into another?

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite setup, with the main site being the company web site and a couple other blogs that will have different themes.

I want to pull in posts from one or the other blog onto the home page of the main blog.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function to get **one post** from **one blog**, but that's it:

```
<?php 
  $post = get_blog_post( $blog_id, $post_id ); 
  echo $post->ID;
?>
```

If the blog has only one author you could also use `get_most_recent_post_of_user`. But I think the best way is to fetch the feed using `fetch_feed()`:

```
$rss = fetch_feed('http://feed.url');
// Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5. 
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5); 
// Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);

foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) { // Loop
    echo $item->get_title();
    echo $item->get_content();
}
```

It uses the [Simplepie API](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/start), I recently wrote an article about that [Display RSS Feed in WordPress](http://marioaguiar.com/en/journal/display-rss-feed-in-wordpress/).